# How to create a critical section with Mutex in Rust?

Tags: rust, synchronization, thread-safety, mutex

I'm new to Rust. I'm supposed to use a `Mutex` and an `Arc` to create a critical section within the `print_lots` function to stop the race condition from happening. Any Ideas?

```
fn main() {
    let num_of_threads = 4;
    let mut array_of_threads = vec![];
    
    for id in 0..num_of_threads {
        array_of_threads.push(std::thread::spawn(move || print_lots(id)));
    }

    for t in array_of_threads {
        t.join().expect("Thread join failure");
    }
}

fn print_lots(id: u32) {
    println!("Begin [{}]", id);
    for _i in 0..100 {
        print!("{} ", id);
    }
    println!("\nEnd [{}]", id);
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want this program to do.  After creating the Mutex for a `u32` (with an initial value of 0), you're never trying to read or write from it again.  What purpose does it have?

Comment: Its the `MutexGuard` which is unused, not the `Mutex`. Read the notes after the warning. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7e8306b5d2f2b01c5be7cbf785f3ebc4

Comment: sorry, I've changed the code and question to make more sense now. I'm basically trying to stop the race condition and I'm not sure how to.

Comment: Where's the race condition in that code though?

Comment: If you want the print statements not to intermingle then the threads would essentially be running in sequence, which kind of defeats the point of using multiple threads at all.

Comment: But you would do that by locking `StdOut`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e5ca73915d7fbf6c9bb20bc5590ccac3

Comment: Consider also [returning the data from the threads, and doing all your printing in the main thread](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f407e24f822128c4324f52603ce7f53c).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

fn main() {
    let num_of_threads = 4;
    let mut array_of_threads = vec![];
    let counter = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0));

    for id in 0..num_of_threads {
        let counter_clone = counter.clone();
        array_of_threads.push(std::thread::spawn(move || print_lots(id, counter_clone)));
    }

    for t in array_of_threads {
        t.join().expect("Thread join failure");
    }
}

fn print_lots(id: u32, c: Arc<Mutex<u32>>) {
    println!("Begin [{}]", id);
    let _guard = c.lock().unwrap();
    for _i in 0..100 {
        print!("{} ", id);
    }
    println!("\nEnd [{}]", id);
}
```

Comment: You can use `Mutex::new(())` to avoid storing a meaningless `0` that will confuse people later. Also note that the lock is still held during `println!("\nEnd [{}]", id);` which might or might not be what you wanted.

Comment: So, if you use a mutex of numeric type (0), you can use it in the same way as std::lock_guard in c++?

Answer (score 4):

`Mutex` in Rust perhaps works differently to how locks work in some other languages you might be used to. Instead of tracking the lock independently from the value, a Rust `Mutex` *owns* the data and prevents accessing it without first obtaining a lock, which is enforced at compile time.

The warning you are getting is because you have locked the `Mutex`, but then done nothing with the value. The warning is there because this is almost certainly a mistake.

```
fn main() {
    let foo = Mutex::new(0);
    // It's often best to just unwrap and panic if the lock is poisoned
    if let Ok(mut lock) = foo.lock() {
        *lock = 2;
        // The mutex is unlocked automatically when lock goes out of scope here
    }
    println!("{:?}", foo); // Mutex { data: 2 }
}
```

I am guessing that your real problem is that you want to synchronise the print statements so that output from different threads is not intermingled.

One way to do that is to obtain a lock on `StdOut` which actually uses a lock internally and provides a similar API to `Mutex`:

```
fn print_lots(id: u32) {
    let stdout = io::stdout();
    println!("Begin [{}]", id);
    let mut handle = stdout.lock();
    for _i in 0..100 {
        write!(&mut handle, "{} ", id).unwrap();
    }
    println!("\nEnd [{}]", id);
    // handle is dropped here, unlocking stdout 
}
```

In your simplified example, creating a long-lived lock in each thread is counterproductive since each thread will block the others and the result is sequential rather than concurrent. This might still make sense though if your real-world code has more going on.